# HTTP 1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I'm getting **'500 Internal Server Error'** in my application.

how to investigate this error.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the Application Event Log on the server. Unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET applications are usually written there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Custom errors off in web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will show the exception details.
Check out the MSDN documentation about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y123fsf7(v=vs.85).aspx